# Regex for more than 10 digits in a mixed string?

Tags: regex

I need to check for users that are putting their id in the wrong input box.

They might enter the id as `123-456-789-012` or `123456789012` or some variation so I can't just check for digits. The length of the id varies slightly per user, but is always more than 10 digits.

Valid input is a mix of characters and 0-10 digits.

I've seen a lot of solutions for plain digits, but not mixed text. I tried variations of

```
(\D*\d){0,10}
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Why not "remove all non-digits" and count the digits?

Comment: (\d|[a-z]|-) do this it will match all digits or alphabets or '-' and you can check if the length of the input string is equal to the length of the captured group

Comment: I have a version that strips out the non-digits and counts what's left, but I'd prefer one step so I can use a RegularExpressionValidator, rather than a CustomValidator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want "0-n non-digits" then "1-10 lots of a digit-and-any-non-digits":

```
^\D*(\d\D*){1,10}$
```

Comment: I want less than 11. a most 10 characters is fine. More than 10 is invalid. Your expression worked perfectly in my RegularExpressionValidator to require at least 10, but when I tried switching "10," to ",11", it just invalidated everything.

Comment: @thchaver as per my previous answer, if you want exactly 10 remove the comma. I have edited out both the comma and the comment regarding that. Try the current version of my regex

Comment: Thank you for your help. I want fewer than 11 digits. For example, "John", "John1", and "John0123456789" are all valid. "John: 0123-4567-890" is invalid.

Comment: @thchaver it now allows between 1 and 10.

Comment: I changed the 1 to a 0 and it worked perfectly. Thanks!